# Showing alert from service class in react-native

Tags: react-native

I have an HTTP service class which is responsible for communication with my Laravel based API. I want the HTTP service class to trigger React Native Alert box when there is a 401 authentication issue. Or 403 Access denied issue or 422 which is validation issue.

I have the basic HTTP service class ready, but I am not able to show an alert from my HTTP service because it is not a react component and I want to know if I can use such a global service class and still trigger Native components.

Below is my code:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import {
  AsyncStorage,
  Alert
} from 'react-native';

class HttpService {
  async get(url) {
    let at = await AsyncStorage.getItem('access_token', (error, accessToken) => {
      return accessToken;
    });

    let data = await axios.get(url, {headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + at }})
      .then(response => {
        console.log('response', response);
        return response;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        let message, title = '';

        if (!error.response) {
          message = error;
        }

        if (error.response.status === 401) {
          message = error.response.data.message;
          title = 'Authentication issue'
        }

        Alert.alert(title, message, [
          { text: 'Ok', onPress: () => console.log(123) }
        ]);
      });

    return data;
  }

  post() {}
}

export default HttpService;
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just return the errors too? So you can determine what occurred so the component that makes the `HttpService` call knows when to show the Alert.

```
class yourComponent extends Component{

  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      token: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      error: null
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    HttpService.get('someUrl')
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          token: res,
          isLoaded: true
        });
      }, (error) => {
        this.setState({
          error: error,
          isLoaded: true
        });
      })      
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, items } = this.state;
    if (error) {
      // return your Alert here
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
      // return loading component;
    } else {
      // return your main component
    }  
  }

}
```

Comment: In this way, I will have to handle the alert in every HTTP call throughout the application. And let's say I want to handle expiry to token, then I will have to duplicate that logic in every component. This doesn't feel right.

Comment: @AmitavRoy you could just make another component just for the Alert and but all the conditional logic there.